# Cannot read properties node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, node-modules

I've got a problem, I wrote a code which should update my user in a db but when I try to do it in Postman I get an information that the programme can't read my property `token`. Could somebody help me?

My `verifytoken.js` code

```
const { response } = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    
    const authHeader = res.headers.token;
    if(authHeader){
        const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SEC, (err, user) => {
            if(err) res.status(403).json("Token isn't valid");
            req.user = user;
            next();
        })
        
    }else{
        return res.status(401).json("You are not authenticated");
    }
}
const verifytokenandauth = (req, res, next) => {
    verifyToken(req, res, ()=>{
        if(req.user.id=== req.params.id || req.user.admin) {
            next();
        }else{
            res.status(403).json("You are not allowed to do this");
        }
    })
}
module.exports = {verifyToken, verifytokenandauth}
```

My `user.js` code

```
const { verifytokenandauth } = require('./verifytoken');
const {User} = require('../models/user');

const router = require('express').Router();
router.put('/:id', verifytokenandauth, async (req, res) => {
        if(req.body.password){
            req.body.password =  CryptoJs.AES.encrypt(req.body.password, process.env.PASS_SEC).toString()
        }
        try{
            const updateduser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.User.id, {
                $set: req.body
            },{new: true});
            res.status(200).json(updateduser);
        }catch(err) {res.status(500).json(err);}
    });

module.exports = router
```

[And screenshot from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwV1D.png)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `const authHeader = res.headers.token;` shouldn't this be `req.headers.token`?

Comment: Is there a reason you are splitting the token?

Comment: @NullDev now it gives '{}' in Postman and error 500

Comment: @jack yes cause this is my token "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzMGRkZDUzZThlOWQ4MGRhNWY3ZjRlMCIsImFkbWluIjpmYWxzZSwiaWF0IjoxNjYxOTQ0NjM5LCJleHAiOjE2NjI1NDk0Mzl9.fVPCyiqTi-4z811dxgtClAoW3Hy1tjW991x5oqBweFo"

Comment: @Z3eme does   jwt.verify accepts an array as first param?